# Azure ARM: Remove invalid characters

Tags: json, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I am looking for an easy way to replace all non-alphanumeric characters from a string (just trying to prevent user's from entering an invalid character for a resource).

My working code is below, but I think it is extremely messy since I have to create a new variable for every character I want to remove.

```
{
  "parameters": {
    "userString": {
    "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "removeChar1": "[replace(parameters('userString'), '-', '')]",
    "removeChar2": "[replace(variables('removeChar1'), ' ', '')]",
    "removeChar3": "[replace(variables('removeChar2'), '^', '')]",
    "cleanString": "[replace(variables('removeChar3'), ')', '')]"
  },
  "resources": [
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "cleanStringOutput": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[variables('cleanString')]"
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are users creating resources through arm templates? What I mean is, haven't they created them first through the portal and then extracted the templated?

Comment: Many Azure deployments, especially for enterprise environments, leverage automation through ARM, terraform, ansible, or equivalent.

Comment: True, but I would say depending on what services you are building, it is almost easier to build it through the portal and get the arm template and automate it for the higher level environments. Unless you are automating pure infrastructure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

no, the replace function only does exact search, so thats the only way to do. "alternatives" include: create a function in your template that does exactly this, but you can call your function (looks a lot cleaner + reusable), create an azure function and call that function, the output of the function would be an arm template with the output string with all the characters replaced.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authoring-templates#functions